# Definition of the derivative

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = x^{3}\cos{\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}, x \not= 0, f(0) = 0$

Show, by definition of the derivative, that $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ and find the derivative of $f$ there.

So we know the derivative is defined as:

$$f'{(x)} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f{(x + h)} - f{(x)}}{h}}$$
So we have:

$$f'{(x)} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{{(x + h)}^{3}\cos{\left(\frac{1}{(x+h)^{2}}\right)} - x^{3}\cos{\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}}{h}}$$

How would I evaluate this limit?

Comment: It's $f(x+h)-f(x)$ at the numerator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is incorrect. The right definition is
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$
With this definition, we get
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^3 \cos (1/h^2)}{h}$$
Can you take it from here? <del>H: Use L'hôpital's rule</del>. EDIT: Forget L'hôpital, which does not apply in this situation! Just note that $|\cos(1/h^2)| \leq 1$ for all $h \neq 0$.

Comment: L'Hôpital? Are you kidding?

Comment: Or note $f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0} h^2 \cos(1/h^2)$ and that $\cos$ is a bounded function.

Comment: How do we evaluate $\lim_{h\to0} h^{2}\cos{(\frac{1}{h^{2}})}$?

Comment: You can use the squeeze theorem for instance: $-1 \leq \cos (1/h^2) \leq 1$, which gives $-h^2 \leq h^2 \cos(1/h^2) \leq h^2$. What happens when $h$ approaches zero?

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, so our limit is $0$